# Eclipse IDE is not opening up

Tags: eclipse, error-handling, ide, restart, error-code

[I am getting this error when end task from task manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmwpg.png)

I tried restarting pc but it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: On the command line, what does `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java" -version` return (should be 64-bit Java 11 or higher)? Better use current Eclipse with embedded Java. Lombok of the version you have might also causing that.